# Collapsing/Merging commits into one changeset

Tags: deployment, mercurial, fabric, bitbucket

currently the way I keep my local and dev server env in sync is with a fabfile.

```
def upload():
 """ upload project dir to the production server. """
extra_opts = '--omit-dir-times'
rsync_project(
    remote_dir=env.remote_dir,
    local_dir=env.local_dir,
    exclude=RSYNC_EXCLUDE,
    delete=True,
    extra_opts=extra_opts,
)
reload_apache()
```

and when I want to pull from the repo i use this

```
def update_source():
    """ Update the project source. """
    with cd(env.directory):
        run('hg fetchanddestroy')
```

where that alias cmd performs this

```
fetchanddestroy = !hg pull && hg update -C
```

How can I collapse a range of changesets into one on bitbucket? I have tried using machg but it just pulls back in all the ones i merged. I am trying to come with a suitable way to deploy my projects on my VPS and keep them in sync with my local repo. In the process of setting up the environment I had to make minor tweaks to the repo which resulted in many changesets being made and pulled on the server. Therefore I want to merge all those small changesets into one, in order to keep my repo history clean.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to keep your repo history "clean"? What is the harm in having a bunch of small commits in there?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand what you are asking but using a branch workflow similar to [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a good way to manage the flow of changes between development and release.

In "short",

- keep all releases in a branch called master
- do all your development in default as you normally would
- at release time create a branch off of master for the release

  $ hg update master && hg branch relv1.0
- merge in what you want from default, for this example assume the latest is what you want.

  $ hg merge default && hg commit -m "merge latest from default"
- if necessary make changes in this branch to make tests pass if applicable and in general get it ready for release whatever that means for your project.

  $ hg commit -m "last minute bug fix...etc"
- When you are confident that the release is ready, tag it, close the branch and merge it into master.

  $ hg  tag "release 1.0" && hg update master && hg merge "release 1.0" && hg commit -m "merge release 1.0"

  $ hg update "release 1.0" && hg commit --close-branch -m "all done"
- and finally get default back in sync with master.

  $ hg update default && hg merge master  # there's a possibility of merge conflicts here, if you have multiple people doing development

  $ hg commit -m "merge release 1.0 from master"
- for deployment, you could just pull latest from master

The overall effect here is that the diff going into master should always represent the combined changes from the default branch since the last release which I think is what you want instead of all the individual changesets that led up to that release.

Obviously there's probably 1000 ways to do it, but I think it's a safe bet that a branching strategy like Git-Flow is ubiquitous enough that your team can understand it and thus follow it.

Another option is using patch queues, that way you have complete control of what goes into a changeset at any given point.